# applicationWillFinishLaunching not being called applescript Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, handler

for some reason, my handler `applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)`
isn't being called when my app starts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place this method in your AppDelegate.applescript file and make sure the AppDelegate is properly linked in IB.

To test this start a new project to see how it's configured correctly. You also can try if another AppDelegate method works like

```
on applicationDidFinishLaunching:aNotification
log "works"
end
```

If this isn't your problem post your code.

Comment: It was working then I don't know why it stopped. Is there anything I should check?

Comment: I imported my code into a test project and it worked. But for some reason, It wont work on my original app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Open IB and select AppDelegate. Check the connections and see if everything is connected as in your test application.

Comment: Where can I find "IB" as you said?

Comment: IB is the short form for interface builder. It's where you build your interface. Here's some basic tutorial: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1942301

Comment: Where in the IB should I look? I have searched quite a bit looking for anything that says "applicationWillFinnishLaunching" but no luck.  The handler only works if my main storyboard is an ".xib" file but when I make it a ".storyboard" it doesn't work.